# What is used to inverse an RC4 cipher?

Tags: encryption, inverse, wep

I'm doing a research paper on WEP, and one of the things that has popped up immediately is that it's possible to obtain the keystream derived from specific IV, denoted RC4(v,k). I won't bother posting the proofs (unless requested), as I'm sure they're online and can be easily found.

The question is:
Once you have the value of RC4(v,k) where v is the IV (which is given) and k is the key (which is not given), how do you find the value of k?

I don't need detailed answers, just pointers in the right direction. I read something about rainbowtables, but I didn't really take the time to understand it. If possible, links would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to an attack by [Fluhrer Mantin and Shamir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluhrer,_Mantin_and_Shamir_attack)